# How to create an array of matrices in python?

Tags: python

How to create an array of matrices in python?

In MATLAB, I do something like this:

```
for i = 1:n
    a{i} = f(i)
end
```

where `f(i)` is a function that returns a random matrix of fixed size.

In python, I am working with numpy but I do not understand how to do this.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([])
for i in range(0, n):
   # a.insert(i, f(i)) and does not work
   # a[i] = f(i)  and does not work
```

Comment: Do you know the shape of the array returned by `f` in advance?

Comment: Yes I know the dimensions of the matrix returned by `f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want a rank-3 Numpy array, and you know the shape of `f(i)` in advance, you can pre-allocate the array:

   ```
   a = np.zeros((n,) + shape)
   for i in range(n):
       a[i] = f(i)
   ```
2. If you just want a list (rather than a Numpy array) of matrices, use a list comprehension:

   ```
   a = [f(i) for i in range(n)]
   ```
3. Another way to get a Numpy array is to convert from the list comprehension above:

   ```
   a = np.array([f(i) for i in range(n)])
   ```

   However, this will be less efficient than #1 because the results of `f(i)` are first buffered in a dynamically-sized list before the Numpy array is built.

Answer (score 2):

The best equivalent of a matlab cell array here is a list in python:

```
a = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append(f(i))
```

Comment: left-over from the question.